# C# Winforms: Simulate user clicks(start- wait for data collection - stop)

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I am writing up a C# application using Winforms, and I need to collect some data based on my selection from a comboBox. I also have a start button that enables data collection, and a stop button that halts the data collection.

This is what I am capable of doing right now:

> Measure all data from all channels by switching my selection on the comboBox (one channel at a time). The process goes like: select a channel- start button click - wait for data collection - stop button click

But here is what I want to do in code:
Select a channel - start button click - wait for data collection  - stop button click
switch to next channel - start button click -wait for data collection - stop button click
................
repeat this process until done.

My question is: what should I adopt to achieve this?
I have been trying to use startButton.PerformClick( ) to enabling the buttons, however, I need to stop for a few seconds in between starting and stopping to wait for data collection.

You may ask why because this is very inefficient, but for some reason the DLL from the third party cannot collect data from all channels at the same time. So i have to manually switch my channel selection from the comboBox in order to collect all data at one go.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    startButton.PerformClick();
    
}
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    stopButton.PerformClick();
}

private void checkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i != 40) //there are a total of 40 channels
    {

        System.Windows.Forms.Timer mytimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        mytimer.Interval = 5000;

        System.Windows.Forms.Timer mytimer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        mytimer2.Interval = 7000;

        mytimer.Start();
        mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);

        mytimer2.Start();
        mytimer2.Tick += new EventHandler(timer2_Tick);

        physicalChannelComboBox.SelectedIndex = i;
        i++;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally you want to move the code out of your button click handler into a method.  Then you simply call that method from the Button click event and from anywhere else in code.  No need to simulate inputs

Comment: How do you know when the data for the channel has been collected?

Comment: @hijinxbassist Thank you for your suggestion. I know that the data is collected because I am storing it to a data table that prints the values of a channel and so I am able to plot it.  I am reading continuous samples in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple routine shell that should help you.  This uses a timer to poll if the data is complete (checking a boolean, which is currently set to true for testing).  In your case you could probably just set the timers tick value to be the delay you want.  If you have a way of knowing when the data is done being collected for the channel, that would be more preferable.  This code runs standalone so you can test and configure it before starting to integrate it into your existing code.  All it requires is a a listbox for viewing the logs.

```
public partial class DataCollectorForm : Form
{
    private Timer timer = new Timer();

    private int numberOfChannels = 40;
    private int currentChannelNumber = 0;

    private DateTime routineStartTime;
    private DateTime routineStopTime;

    private DateTime channelStartTime;
    private DateTime channelStopTime;

    public DataCollectorForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer.Interval = 250;
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

        DataCollectionRoutineStart();
    }


    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Need to check if data collection for this channel is complete..
        // 
        var isDoneCollectingData = true; 
        if (isDoneCollectingData)
        {
            ChannelDataCollectionStop();

            currentChannelNumber++;
            
            if (currentChannelNumber >= numberOfChannels)
            {
                DataCollectionRoutineComplete();
            }
            else
            {
                ChannelDataCollectionStart();
            }
        }
    }
    public void DataCollectionRoutineStart()
    {
        routineStartTime = DateTime.Now;

        Log("Data Collection Routine Start");

        currentChannelNumber = 0;

        ChannelDataCollectionStart();

        timer.Start();
    }
    private void ChannelDataCollectionStart()
    {
        channelStartTime = DateTime.Now;

        Log("Data Collection Start : channel " + currentChannelNumber);
    }
    private void ChannelDataCollectionStop()
    {
        channelStopTime = DateTime.Now;

        Log("Data Collection Stop : channel " + currentChannelNumber + " : elapsed " + (channelStopTime - channelStartTime));
    }
    private void DataCollectionRoutineComplete()
    {
        routineStopTime = DateTime.Now;

        timer.Stop();

        Log("Data Collection Routine Complete : elapsed " + (routineStopTime - routineStartTime));
    }



    private void Log(string msg)
    {
        loggingListBox.Items.Add(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This routine really helps with the purpose that I am trying to achieve with my code. Thanks again.

Comment: And I have just integrated into my own code, it works exactly the way that I want it to. You are truly amazing. I am a newbie to C# and Winforms, there is a long way to go but I am very glad that I am learning to do it !

Comment: Happy to hear it worked and glad I was able to help you solve your task.   Please mark this answer to close the question.  Happy coding!